# About Android in-app billing verification mechanism

Tags: android

In the sample code of Android in-app billing, the logic of verification is written in the app, and the json string returned from the market server is just in form of human-understandable plain text without any encryption.
  If someone is very proficient in de-compiling, the whole verification would be very vulnerable. In addition, the verification only guarantee the transaction process of paying money to the market server, but ignore the security of the transaction or delivery of virtual goods, which brings out the problem about how we guarantee the security verification of the billing between the app and our own server, for example preventing intentionally changing the purchase state returned from the market server before sending it to our own server?

Answer (score 0):

for buying from android market you need to provide a nonce .This nonce is just a random long value.The JSON contains that nonce based on nonce you can verify if it was sent by you.

Comment: apps are to be signed by your public key.User must know this to communicate with market.

Comment: What if the hacker changes other information e.g. the "purchase state"  in the JSON string in the app? My own server cannot figure out its validity. And hackers may capture the public key even if I send it from my server the the app after de-compiling my app's apk?

Comment: no what i meant was after decompiling your apk the apk need to be signed again by public key which has to be yours so then only the market will identify it as valid.and you dont need to send public key.IF you have referred to google's sample.All logic security.java has to be server-side.